# Spark Kafka WordCount Python

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, pyspark

I've just started playing with apache spark and trying to get the kafka wordcount to work in python. I've decided to use python as its a language I'll be able to use for other big data tech and also DataBricks are offering their courses through spark.

My question:
I'm running the basic wordcount example from here: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/streaming/kafka_wordcount.py
It seems to kick off and connect to the kafka logs but I can't see it actually produce a word count. I then added the below lines to write to a text file and it just produces a bunch of empty text file. It is connecting to the kafka topic and there is data in the topic, how can I see what its actually doing with the data if anything? Could it be a timing thing? Cheers.

Code for processing kafka data

```
                counts = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split("|")) \
                    .map(lambda word: (word, 1)) \
                    .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b) \
                    .saveAsTextFiles("sparkfiles")
```

Data in Kafka topic

```
                    16|16|Mr|Joe|T|Bloggs
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I was being an idiot. When I produced data to the topic **while the spark app was running** I can see the following in the output

```
                (u'a', 29)
                (u'count', 29)
                (u'This', 29)
                (u'is', 29)
                (u'so', 29)
                (u'words', 29)
                (u'spark', 29)
                (u'the', 29)
                (u'can', 29)
                (u'sentence', 29)
```

This represents how many times each word was represented in the block that was just processed by spark.